# How to get the minimum value of all positive values in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores positive and negative float values:

```
    id |  value
-----------------        
    1  |  -13.334
    2  |   2.33
    3  |   1.04
    4  |  -5.02
    5  |   30.11
```

How can I get the minimum value of all positives? in my example it should be `1.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WHERE` to filter only positive values:

```
SELECT MIN(value)
FROM tab
WHERE value > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT MIN(value)
FROM table      
WHERE value > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter using where

```
SELECT min(value) 
from my_table  
where value  >= 0
```